# GoogleCredentials does not work and paralyzes the application

Tags: firebase

I followed the steps of the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=0

But the "GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)" part of the code ; it stops the application and does not return anything, not even an error message.

I have included the following libraries

- firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar
- google-auth-library-credentials-0.15.0.jar
- google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.15.0.jar
- appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.74.jar

Please give me some help, thanks

```
        String token=null;
        FirebaseOptions options=null;
        FileInputStream serviceAccount=null;                    
        try {
            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(Aplicacion.ruta_firebase_js);            
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            log("Ruta de clave de firebase no encontrada: "+ex.getMessage());
        }           

        if(serviceAccount!=null){ 
            try {

                GoogleCredentials gc=GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);                
                log(gc.toString());
                options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                        .setCredentials(gc)
                        .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxx-xxxxxx.firebaseio.com")
                        .build();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
                log("Ruta de clave de firebase no encontrada: "+ex.getMessage());
            }catch (IOException ex){ 
                log("Error autenticando en Firebase: "+ex.getMessage());
            } 
        }


        if(options!=null){ 
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);                    
            try {
                String uid = "Rocco-ergvrw98";
                token = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid);
                HashMap p=new HashMap();
                p.put("accion", "tokenfirebase");
                p.put("token", token);
                Rocco.servidor_enlinealizate.enviar(indice, p); 

            } catch (FirebaseAuthException ex) {
                log("Error obtenmiendo token: "+ex.getMessage());
            };
        }
        return token;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I had to include these bookstores in my project

- api-common-1.8.1
- commons-logging-1.2
- firebase-admin-6.8.1
- google-api-client-1.29.0
- google-http-client-1.29.1
- google-http-client-gson-1.29.1
- google-http-client-jackson2-1.29.1
- google-oauth-client-1.29.0
- gson-2.8.5
- guava-27.1-jre
- httpclient-4.5.8
- httpcore-4.4.11
- jackson-core-2.9.9
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.13
- jsr305-3.0.2
- protobuf-java-3.8.0
- slf4j-api-1.7.26
- slf4j-simple-1.7.26
- xpp3-1.1.6

Whose updated versions are available in https://mvnrepository.com/